How can I find the first row that meets conditions of a mask for each group?
This is my DataFrame:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y'],
        'b': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        'c': [9, 8, 11, 13, 14, 3, 104, 106, 11, 100, 70, 7]
    }
)

Expected output: Creating column out:
    a  b    c    out
0   x  1    9    NaN
1   x  1    8    NaN
2   x  1   11    NaN
3   x  2   13  found
4   x  2   14    NaN
5   y  1    3    NaN
6   y  1  104  found
7   y  1  106    NaN
8   y  2   11    NaN
9   y  2  100    NaN
10  y  2   70    NaN
11  y  2    7    NaN

The mask is:
mask = (df.c > 10)

The process: Grouping is by column a:
a) For each group, finding the first row that meets the conditions of the mask.
b) For group x this condition only applies when b == 2. That is why row 3 is selected.
And this is my attempt. It is getting close but it feels like this is not the way:
def func(g):
    mask = (g.c > 10)
    g.loc[mask.cumsum().eq(1) & mask, 'out'] = 'found'
    return g

df = df.groupby('a').apply(func)


One option with groupby.idxmax:
mask = (df['c'] > 10) & (df['a'].ne('x') | df['b'].eq(2))

idx = mask.groupby(df['a']).idxmax()
df.loc[idx[mask.loc[idx].values], 'out'] = 'found'

Another with groupby.transform:
mask = (df['c'] > 10) & (df['a'].ne('x') | df['b'].eq(2))

df.loc[mask & mask.groupby(df['a'])
                  .transform(lambda m: (~m).shift(fill_value=True)
                                           .cummin()),
       'out'] = 'found'

Output, with an extra group z that has no match:
    a  b    c    out
0   x  1    9    NaN
1   x  1    8    NaN
2   x  1   11    NaN
3   x  2   13  found
4   x  2   14    NaN
5   y  1    3    NaN
6   y  1  104  found
7   y  1  106    NaN
8   y  2   11    NaN
9   y  2  100    NaN
10  y  2   70    NaN
11  y  2    7    NaN
12  z  3    1    NaN
13  z  3    1    NaN

last match
to get the last match (instead of the first one), just inver the mask:
Example:
mask = (df['c'] > 10) & (df['a'].ne('x') | df['b'].eq(2))

mask = mask[::-1]

idx = mask.groupby(df['a']).idxmax()
df.loc[idx[mask.loc[idx].values], 'out'] = 'found'

    a  b    c    out
0   x  1    9    NaN
1   x  1    8    NaN
2   x  1   11    NaN
3   x  2   13    NaN
4   x  2   14  found
5   y  1    3    NaN
6   y  1  104    NaN
7   y  1  106    NaN
8   y  2   11    NaN
9   y  2  100    NaN
10  y  2   70  found
11  y  2    7    NaN
12  z  3    1    NaN
13  z  3    1    NaN


Thanks a lot. This is not my expected output. Take a look at step b please

@AmirX just change the mask, see update ;)

Thanks. I asked about your crypto wallet before. Can you add one to your profile? I really appreciate your support. Means A LOT.

@AmirX I hadn't seen this request, and I don't have any ;)

Just add one to your profile. I have seen some developers do that. It is not that hard to make one of them :)

I don't really support cryptocurrencies, they are not good for the planet. I have a support link in my profile if you want.

If I want to find the last instance instead of the first one, cummin should change to cummax? Should I open a new post? I tweaked the code but didn't work.

@AmirX keep it easy, just invert your mask mask = mask[::-1] before running the code ;)

Here's an approach without the need for groupby:
n = 10

m = df['c'].where(~(df['a'].eq('x') & df['b'].ne(2)), n).gt(n)
m = df[m].duplicated(subset='a')

df['out'] = m[~m].replace(False, 'found')

Output
    a  b    c    out
0   x  1    9    NaN
1   x  1    8    NaN
2   x  1   11    NaN
3   x  2   13  found
4   x  2   14    NaN
5   y  1    3    NaN
6   y  1  104  found
7   y  1  106    NaN
8   y  2   11    NaN
9   y  2  100    NaN
10  y  2   70    NaN
11  y  2    7    NaN

Explanation

First, use Series.where to 'clip' values that need to be ignored for group x at 10 and check Series.gt (here stored as m).
Next, use boolean indexing with m and get duplicates on subset=a with Series.duplicated. This will give False by default for the first match.
Finally, use inverse boolean indexing for m (i.e. using ~) itself, chain Series.replace to turn True into 'found', and assign to your new column.


@AmirX, in the comments for the answer by @mozway you asked: "If I want to find the last instance instead of the first one, cummin should change to cummax?". With my method you would want to change: df[m].duplicated(subset='a') into df[m].duplicated(subset='a', keep='last').

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
    
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'a': ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y'],
        'b': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        'c': [9, 8, 11, 13, 14, 3, 104, 106, 11, 100, 70, 7]
})
    
print(df)
"""
    a  b    c
0   x  1    9
1   x  1    8
2   x  1   11
3   x  2   13
4   x  2   14
5   y  1    3
6   y  1  104
7   y  1  106
8   y  2   11
9   y  2  100
10  y  2   70
11  y  2    7
"""
    
# Conditions for 'found'
mask_found_x = (df['c'] > 10) & (df['a'] == 'x') & (df['b'] == 2)
mask_found_y = (df['c'] > 10) & (df['a'] != 'x')

# Identify the first occurrence of 'x' within each group (a)
first_found_x = mask_found_x.groupby(df['a']).transform(pd.Series.cumsum) == 1
#print(df[first_found_x])
# Identify the first occurrence of 'y' within each group (a)
first_found_y = mask_found_y.groupby(df['a']).transform(pd.Series.cumsum) == 1
#print(df[first_found_y])

# Combine conditions and assign 'found' or NaN
df['out'] =  np.where(first_found_x | first_found_y ,'Found', np.nan)  
print(df)
"""
   a  b    c    out
0   x  1    9    nan
1   x  1    8    nan
2   x  1   11    nan
3   x  2   13  Found
4   x  2   14    nan
5   y  1    3    nan
6   y  1  104  Found
7   y  1  106    nan
8   y  2   11    nan
9   y  2  100    nan
10  y  2   70    nan
11  y  2    7    nan
"""

